# Component not accepting camelCase names

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

My issue here lie with me trying to make a navbar component, some data must be shared from the main page to the component, and while spending a few hours researching into how to use components, i can find nowhere that can explain why i cant use camelCase variable names to bind data.

Can anyone point me to a resource to explain this to me, or better yet is there a way to use camelCase to bind data, it will make my code an easier read for the team;giving me a more diverse range of names for data.

**SAMPLE CODE:**
**HTML**

```
<navbar-component theme="newux" class="screenOnly" title='projData'
                  titleId='vm.titleData' data='{{vm.project.id}}'>
</navbar-component>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
  bindings: {
    theme: "@",
    title:"@",
    titleId:"<",
    data:"@"
  }
```

Comment: E.G titleId wont work however the other bindings do

Comment: Doesn't seem like an angular component to me. I have removed the tag for you, good luck with your issue !

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: angularjs, i think its 1.5+

Comment: HTML is case-insensitive. HTML5 parsers convert mixed-case attributes to lowercase when building the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a binding to a camel-cased property, you have to use a dash when setting it through an attribute. e.g.:

```
<navbar-component theme="newux" 
                  class="screenOnly" 
                  title='projData' 
                  title-id='vm.titleData' 
                  data='{{vm.project.id}}'>
</navbar-component>
```

Comment: So what is the reason javascript/angularjs needs this to be done?

Comment: It's called "attribute normalization" and is discussed in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). It's a way to consistently handle things across different developer preferences and browser implementations.

Comment: Also be careful with attributes that start with `data-`. The prefix is stripped during normalization. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Attribute Normilization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

Comment: 3 days I've spent on this issue until I came across this answer. thank you :)